# Como juntar 3 Select em um Só

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer um `SELECT` aonde  eu consiga trazer o mesmo resultando porém em um único `SELECT`.

Exemplo do select  que preciso que seja em único:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS QtdTarifados
FROM    tblLoteTESTE
WHERE   CodCampanha         = 1
    AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7
    AND YEAR(DataAgendada)  = 2018
    AND FlagTarifado        = 1

SELECT  COUNT(*) AS QtdEnviados
FROM    tblLoteTESTE
WHERE   CodCampanha         = 1
    AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7
    AND YEAR(DataAgendada)  = 2018
    AND FlagEnviado         = 1

SELECT  COUNT(*) AS QtdRespondidos
FROM    tblLoteTESTE
WHERE   CodCampanha         = 1
    AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7
    AND YEAR(DataAgendada)  = 2018
    AND FlagRespondido      = 1
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou `UNION`? Sabe como fazer?

Comment: Você pode utilizar todos seus selects como subselects de um principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retire o filtro para cada flag e some condicionando, usando o `case when`, vc pode colocar mais cláusulas.

A ideia é:

```
select sum(case when [condição específica que conta no campo_1]
                then 1 
                else 0
           end) campo_1,
       sum(case when [condição específica que conta no campo_2]
                then 1 
                else 0
           end) campo_2
  from tabela
 where [condições gerais para todos os campos totalizadores]
```

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT sum(case when FlagTarifado = 1 then 1 else 0 end) QtdTarifados,
       sum(case when FlagEnviado = 1 then 1 else 0 end) QtdEnviados,
       sum(case when FlagRespondido = 1 then 1 else 0 end) QtdRespondidos
  FROM tblLoteTESTE
 WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Melissa ^^

Answer (score 1):

Utilize Union all para juntar todos os seus selects em um

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QtdTarifados  ,0  AS QtdEnviados   ,0  AS QtdRespondidos FROM tblLoteTESTE
WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018  AND FlagTarifado = 1

UNION ALL

 SELECT 0 AS QtdTarifados  , COUNT(*)   AS QtdEnviados   ,0  AS QtdRespondidos FROM tblLoteTESTE                                    
WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018  AND FlagEnviado = 1

UNION ALL


 SELECT 0 AS QtdTarifados  , 0  AS QtdEnviados  ,COUNT(*)   AS QtdRespondidos FROM tblLoteTESTE                                                    
WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018  AND FlagRespondido = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias maneiras de chegar ao resultado desejado, umas podem ser mais custosas em nível de processamento, então vale a pena dar uma atenção nisso. Por exemplo, você pode utilizar como subquery dentro de um select principal:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblLoteTESTE
 WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018  AND FlagTarifado = 1) AS QtdTarifados,

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS QtdEnviados  FROM tblLoteTESTE
 WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018  AND FlagEnviado = 1) AS QtdEnviados,

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS QtdRespondidos  FROM tblLoteTESTE
 WHERE CodCampanha = 1 AND MONTH(DataAgendada) = 7 AND YEAR(DataAgendada) = 2018  AND FlagRespondido = 1) AS QtdRespondidos
```

Comment: Obrigado Galera !